# Rectangle Geometry from RectF's data does not include RectF's center

Tags: java, android, measure, jts

I can't get to transform a RectF into a Geometry and then detect a point in it:

```
public static Geometry RectFtoGeometry(RectF r) {
    GeometricShapeFactory gsf = new GeometricShapeFactory();
    gsf.setBase(new Coordinate(r.left, r.bottom));
    gsf.setNumPoints(4);
    gsf.setWidth(r.width());
    gsf.setHeight(r.height());

    Geometry rect = gsf.createRectangle(), 
        point = new GeometryFactory().createPoint(new Coordinate(r.centerX(), r.centerY()));

    if(!rect.contains(point))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();//This gets thrown

    return gsf.createRectangle();
}
```

How can I create a Geometry from a RectF that "can contain" its points?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in GeometricShapeFactory.java creates the envelope by using:

```
public Envelope getEnvelope() {
  if (base != null) {
    return new Envelope(base.x, base.x + width, base.y, base.y + height);
  }
  ...
}
```

Android has the origin (0,0) at the left TOP; you have to sum the TOP of the RectF to its height to get the bottom of the RectF. So the base must be:

```
gsf.setBase(new Coordinate(r.left, r.top));
```